Why don't the Jews see Isaiah 53 as being messianic?
In Isaiah 53 it talks about a suffering servant, this verse is commonly used by Christians as talking about Jesus of Nazareth, but I was wondering what are the main objections from the Jewish perspective on Isaiah 53 being messianic?

53rd chapter or a specific sentence within another chapter and if so which one?

Also this is a question about comparative religion which is not on topic for this site

DEAR SIR: You can ask "how do Jews read Isaiah 53?" Or "what sort of ancestry is needed for a king to be Davidic"? But please CEASE AND DESIST from questions that start off with "well the Christians say X, why don't the Jews?" Your starting point is that your way is right, and we have to somehow prove otherwise.

This question is similar to: The suffering servant? Yeshayahu- Isaiah - Chapter 53. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is the 6th out of the 6 questions you asked being closed. Please read very carefully the FAQ about what is in scope here, e.g., here and there

Check out any of the videos of Tovia Singer https://www.youtube.com/@ToviaSinger1

Some key points:

The suffering servant in Isaiah 53 is a reference to the Jewish people as a whole, and this is clear as day. See Isaiah 41:8-9, 44:1-2, 44:21, 45:4, 48:20, 49:3*; Psalms 136:22; Jeremiah 30:10, 46:27-28.
Isaiah uses the singular for the Jews as a whole, see 43:10, 52:1-2 (Christian bibles tampered with these verses and switched them to plural - gaslighting! See also 53:8 "to them" egregiously mistranslated as "to him"), 54:1-8. See also Hoshea 11:1, Exodus 4:22.
In 53, the nations of the world are talking, not the Jews. See the end of 52. See also Micha 7:15-16; Isaiah 41:11; Jeremiah 16:19-20.

There is much more, such as how

the word "virgin" is a deliberate and egregious mistranslation;
Matthew misquotes Scripture to support his nativity narrative;
it is the Jews who suffer for the world, who went to their deaths silently like sheep to the slaughter, as a direct result of the nations' iniquities;
it is the Jew who is despised and afflicted by the nations without cause;
it is the Jews who will be ultimately saved by Hashem's "Arm", and the nations will be shocked at their vindication and come to see their righteousness and how they were always true to God;
it is the Jews who will intercede on behalf of the nations (see Jeremiah 29:7 also)

I suggest getting the full material for the following work, but for now, to get a general feel for why the Jews reject the Christians' claim, I would like to quote the introduction to Rabbi Tovia Singers section on Isaiah 53, in his course book "Let's Get Biblical" Vol 1.

Christians are so convinced that Jesus is the messiah, they are
utterly astounded that the Jews, of all people, consider this claim
preposterous. Christians are bewildered by this rejection because it
appears so obvious to them that every aspect of Jesus' life - from his
miraculous conception to his crucifixion and ressurection - was
clearly predicted in the Jewish Scriptures. They wonder why the Jews
then fail to embrace Jesus as their messiah. Can't they grasp that the
prophecies in their own Bible predict that the messiah would suffer
and die and then rise from the grave? How can a people who produced so
many Nobel Prize winners be so dense? Are they just plain stubborn?
Why then did the Jews reject the claim that the messiah would suffer
and die for the sins of the world? The answer is quite simple: Jewish
messianic expectations are firmly rooted in hundreds of prophecies
recorded throughout the Hebrew Bible. And Jews who are anticipating a
messiah are not looking for anyone remotely like Jesus. They are
awaiting the messiah who will destroy the enemies of God, usher in
worldwide peace, the universal knowledge of God, the ingathering of
the exiles, the resurrection of the dead, and the rebuilding of the
Temple in Jerusalem.
Who then was Jesus?
While it is difficult to answer this question with certainty because
no contemporaneous historian mentioned Jesus, it is possible that he
was one of hundreds—perhaps thousands—of obscure, itinerant preachers
during the first century who came from the backwoods of the Galilee,
wound up on the wrong side of the law, and was summarily executed by
the empire. He then would have been one of hundreds of thousands of
Jews who were crucified by the Romans during the turbulent first
century.
For Jews, calling Jesus the messiah and God, Creator of the universe,
is foolish and blasphemous.
But aren’t there Scriptures that Christians frequently cite like
Isaiah 53 and Psalm 22 that predict that the messiah would be tortured
and killed for the sins of mankind?
The answer to this question is simple as well: the messiah is never
mentioned in any of these chapters. Look it up for yourself! As it
turns out, originally these passages had nothing to do with a future
messiah. These chapters were ripped out of context and key words were
mistranslated. Prior to the advent of Christianity, there was not a
single prediction by anyone that the messiah would be executed for the
sins of mankind. In fact, these texts do not refer to the messiah but
to someone or something else.
This raises an important question: If there was no expectation that
the messiah would die for the sins of the world, how did Jews, who
were among the earliest Christians, come to believe in a suffering
messiah? It is not difficult to figure out how this belief could have
developed.
If Jesus was proclaiming that the tyranny of Rome would soon come to
an end—which would explain what got him into trouble with the
empire—some people may have considered him to be the messiah in a
traditional Jewish sense: he would fulfill prophecies which predict
that a final Davidic ruler would drive Israel’s oppressors out of the
Holy Land and restore the complete sovereignty of God on earth. This
hope would have been shattered when Jesus failed to fulfill this
dream, and instead was summarily executed by the Romans. While some of
his followers presumably concluded that their belief was therefore
unfounded, others came to believe that Jesus somehow rose from the
dead and was the son of God. This was their line of reasoning: Jesus
is the messiah. Jesus was crucified. Therefore, the messiah had to be
crucified.
But this belief raised a monumental problem for these zealous
believers: There were no prophecies in the Jewish Scriptures that
suggested that the messiah was to suffer and die. They solved this
problem by searching the Bible for any support for their new belief.
The verses they came up with, however, do not refer to the messiah,
but rather the suffering of God’s faithful remnant. When they tried to
convince fellow Jews that passages in the Hebrew Bible were speaking
about Jesus the messiah, the sparks began to fly!
It is precisely for this reason that until this day Christians are
baffled by the Jewish rejection of Jesus, and Jews are bewildered why
Christians would even entertain the notion that Jesus is the messiah.
The belief that the messiah was to suffer and die is an idea that
early Christians invented. Not surprisingly, years after Christians
concocted this idea, Paul viewed this notion as the greatest
“stumbling block” for Jews, and because Jews considered this belief so
foolish it had to be true (I Corinthians 1:18-25).

* And note, different chapters do not necessarily mean different topics, and certainly not in these cases, as the book of Isaiah is a cohesive prophecy, and all of these verses are part of the same narrative that 53 is a continuation of.

There are certainly some Jewish sources which view (at least part of) Isaiah 53 as a messianic prophecy, but there is no reason to believe that the Messiah alluded to is Jesus.
See, for example, Sanhedrin 98b:

ורבנן אמרי חיוורא דבי רבי שמו שנאמר (ישעיהו נג, ד) אכן חליינו הוא נשא ומכאובינו סבלם ואנחנו חשבנוהו נגוע מוכה אלהים ומעונה
And the Rabbis say: The leper of the house of Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi is his [the Messiah's] name, as it is stated: “Indeed our illnesses he did bear and our pains he endured; yet we did esteem him injured, stricken by God, and afflicted” (Isaiah 53:4)

